# What are differences between 'Revert', 'Revert Commit' and 'Reset Current Branch to Here' with GitHub in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I use GitHub in Android Studio. I find there are three commands 'Revert', 'Revert Commit' and 'Reset Current Branch to Here' in Android Studio.

You can see Image 1, Image 2.

What are differences between them?

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image: thub]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Revert Commit

It will create a new Commit with undo of all the changes in that particular commit, if you choose IBM Freeze 21, it will undo all the changes in the IBM Freeze 21 commit and create a new one. or see example screenshot. it will revert changes of the commit I selected.

[image: Example of Revert Commit]

## Reset Current Branch to Here...

This will reset the current branch HEAD to the selected commit, e.g IBM Freeze 21, leaves working directory as is. As if you started the whole branch from the new, selected, position and haven't committed yet.

[image: Example Reset Current Branch]

## Revert

It will show a popup window, which will have all the changes in all files after last commit, you can choose any single file or multiple files to revert back to the last commit, like shown in the image below

[image: Revert Changes PopUp]

Answer (score 0):

### Image 2

It is pretty clear.

### Revert Commit

Reverts the selected commit. Creates a new commit exactly the inverse of the commit it is reversing.

### Reset Current Branch to Here...

Moves HEAD to the selected position, leaves working directory as is. As if you started the whole branch from the new, selected, position and haven't committed yet.

## Image 1

Not sure. Either reverts not staged changes, resets staged changes, or both.

Comment: Does it mean that 'Revert Commit' revert only the selected commit and 'Revert' revert all commit?

Comment: @HelloCW no, it doesn't.